# Setting Paperclip attachments with Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

in my users_controller.rb I'm trying to set the profile picture of a user based on a the school that they were identified with through Paperclip.

I have the complete paperclip model setup, and it works with uploading images, but now I am removing the upload images feature in exchange for set images in the asset pipeline under /app/assets/images.

How should I set the images? I'm hoping for something to work like this:

```
if current_user.school == "SCHOOL1"
    current_user.avatar = "SCHOOL1.png"
```

I tried to make this work by replacing the `"SCHOOL1.png"` part above with `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('SCHOOL1.png')` but that isn't working.

Please help!~

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you put your images in `public/` folder and referer with:

```
"#{Rails.root}/public/schools/SCHOOL1.png"
```

If keep not working, try to open image as file before set model attribute:

```
imageFile = File.open "#{Rails.root}/public/schools/SCHOOL1.png"
current_user.avatar = imageFile
```